# How can I stop SKAction

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

```
    _pipeTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"p2"];                                     
    _pipeTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    _pipeTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"p1"];                                     
    _pipeTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    CGFloat distanceToMove = self.frame.size.width + 2 * _pipeTexture1.size.width;                  
    SKAction* movePipes = [SKAction moveByX:-distanceToMove y:0 duration:0.01 * distanceToMove];    
    SKAction* removePipes = [SKAction removeFromParent];                                            
    _movePipesAndRemove = [SKAction sequence:@[movePipes, removePipes]];                            

    SKAction* spawn = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnPipes) onTarget:self];               
    SKAction* delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0];                                               
    SKAction* spawnThenDelay = [SKAction sequence:@[spawn, delay]];                                 
    SKAction* spawnThenDelayForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:spawnThenDelay];                
    [self runAction:spawnThenDelayForever];
```

How can i stop the animation action For some certain scenes?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [SKNode documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeActionForKey%3a) you can use `-(void)runAction:(SKAction *)action withKey:(NSString *)key` to assign a name to the action when you first run it. Then you can later remove it with `- (void)removeActionForKey:(NSString *)key`.

Comment: Determining when you want to stop it is up to you.